# Need help on easing scroll in css3

Tags: html, css, scroll, effect

Can someone help me how can I get the scroll effect similar to this site.
http://www.starworksgroup.com/
I am working on a single page website that has content structure similar to the reference site .

Comment: I am newbie in js n css3 . It will be grateful if some one can show me the demo in js fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a JavaScript implementation, and it is not possible to achieve this with CSS. Try disabling JS and refreshing, watch it break.

[Here](http://www.starworksgroup.com/wp-content/themes/starworksgroup/dist/js/app/app.max.js) is a link to the JS file from that WP theme.

Answer (score 0):

Inmplement jQuery
And add this script :)

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript">
> $(function() {
> $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
> if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'')        
> && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
>   var target = $(this.hash);
>   target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
>   if (target.length) {
>     $('html,body').animate({
>       scrollTop: target.offset().top
>     }, 1000);
>     return false;
>     }
>   }
> });
> });
> ```